# How can a Sex Offender Travel to UK without a harrowing experience?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, criminal-records

I was convicted in 2010 of enticement - a Class C felony. As a high school teacher I had a relationship with a 15 year old student. That relationship ended up lasting 9 years. The former student waited 9 years to bring about the case.

I have just returned from London Heathrow.  I flew there on Tuesday and was detained at the Immigration desk.  I spent 23 hours in a holding room without my luggage and could only make one phone call to my family who had already made it into London.  The officers were very nice and professional, but it was very traumatic for me and my family.  After scanning my passport, the officer took me into a room where I was questioned.  I was fingerprinted.  A photo was made of me.

Hours later, I did a detailed interview with two officers that were asking questions about my 23 year old crime.  The officers seemed to understand the situation completely, however, they told me it was ultimately up to their superior officer.  Hours later, I was given a document denying me entry for the public good.  They put me on a plane the next day and I arrived home last night.

Before I left, I asked to speak to a superior officer.  I asked him if there was anything I should have done differently.  He suggested I fill out an application for a visa next time and wait for the results.  However, I have also read online that they can still refuse you entry even if you show them an approved visa.  Can anyone provide me with some guidance on this?  I want to visit the UK in a couple of years to take my children there on a historical tour and I can't stand for this to happen again.

Comment: What was your sentence? It seems unlikely that a visa application would be successful after a denial of entry on public good grounds. s2 9.3.1. of the Immigration rules state “An application for entry clearance, permission to enter or permission to stay **must** be refused where the applicant’s presence in the UK is not conducive to the public good” (emphasis added) https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

Comment: What you need is called an **entry clearance**. If granted, the matter would then be considered resolved and should pose no problem at immigration. [ECB3: What is entry clearance? - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/what-is-entry-clearance-ecb03/ecb3-what-is-entry-clearance)

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not necessarily. Entry clearance can be cancelled at the border on suitability grounds https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal The OP should probably get advice on applying from an immigration lawyer

Comment: @Traveller 17 - I was given 5 years probation.  I have been compliant ever since.

Answer (score 14):

I believe you will never be allowed to enter the UK.

> Paragraphs 9.4.1.(c) and 9.4.2.(c) provide that an application **must be refused** or permission cancelled where a person has committed an offence which caused serious harm.

> An offence that has caused ‘serious harm’ means an offence that has caused
> serious physical or psychological harm to a victim or victims, or that has contributed to a widespread problem that causes serious harm to a community or to society in general.

> Where a person has been convicted of one or more violent, drugs-related, racially-motivated or sexual offences, they will normally be considered to have been convicted of an offence that has caused serious harm.

> An offence may have caused serious harm even if the punishment imposed for the offence would not normally lead to an application being refused. For example, a person may have been convicted of a sexual offence and only received a 3-month custodial sentence. You must take into account any available offender management reports and any sentencing remarks made by the judge relating to the impact on the victim.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1032285/Criminality.pdf

I'd suggest applying for a visa will be a waste of time for you, and per the title of your question, for any sex offender.

Comment: In this case (23 years later ; victim and offender had a 9 year relationship ; charges only after relationship ended ; low chance of repeat) a review could lead to conclusion that the OP poses no danger to the community or to society in general: *That relationship ended up lasting 9 years. The former student waited 9 years to bring about the case.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson Harsh as this may seem from the OP’s perspective, I think you are missing the point. Many victims of abuse wait years before bringing a claim, the time elapsed in this case doesn’t diminish the offence of an adult in a position of trust and authority having a relationship with a minor.

Answer (score 7):

> He suggested I fill out an application for a visa next time and wait for the results

If you have a criminal record, it is definitely the best thing to do

> However, I have also read online that they can still refuse you entry even if you show them an approved visa

Entering a country you don't hold the citizenship of is *never* a right, having a visa will make it way easier for you to enter, but they can do *whatever* they want with you